# How to locate the source for font warnings?

Tags: fonts

I am preparing my dissertation nowadays, and I wrote a command to generate the title page automatically.

On the title page the fonts used are `\mdseries`, `\bfseries` and `\scshape`. When I use the TeX Gyre Pagella font, it throws a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/qpl/m/sl' in size <12> not available
```

But when I use something else, e.g. New TX, no warning is thrown.

I understand the warning, but its placement is odd, since no fonts are slanted (or italics) anywhere in the code or the output.

---

Here is a somewhat minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\submissiondate}{}
\newcommand{\submitted}[1]{\renewcommand{\submissiondate}{#1}}
\newcommand{\theadvisor}{}
\newcommand{\advisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\theadvisor}{#1}}

\newcommand{\titlepage}{%
\scshape
\vspace{4em}

\begin{center}
\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}
\vspace{3em}

\normalsize
Doctoral dissertation

\small By

\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries\scshape\theauthor\scshape\mdseries
\vspace{30em}

Submitted\\
\submissiondate
\end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{How to not suck at things}
\author{Ink Blot}
\submitted{Decembuary 2017}
\advisor{Professor Professorson}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure at all about the tags. So if someone could help me retag this properly, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Slanted fonts are sometimes used at the running head. And you can minimize a copy of your document to find out the place of the font usage. Just comment out parts of the document and do another LaTeX run.

Comment: No, the page style is plain, no page numbers appear (obviously). Not to mention that I don't use any slanted fonts in the headers either (custom header/footer with `fancyhdr`).

Comment: My psychic power level is to low to find an anwer without any information. Please show a MWE.

Comment: Ask, and you shalt receive.

Comment: Slanted type is used by default for headers; the message points to `\end{document}`: apparently `memoir` is trying to typeset the header and issues the message because it is doing `\slshape`. It's this command that triggers the warning, not actually typesetting text.

Comment: @egreg: How egregious of them. Thanks! (For what it's worth, in the not-minimal code, the message pointed exactly to the line of `\titlepage`.)

Comment: You know what's really annoying here, right? The fact that nobody else in these hallways would have even cared about this warning. But I cannot even get back to the actual writing until I see that warning gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the page number. An gobbled page number is still printed (without output), so the font change for the page number is still done. Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` and it will not be printed and therefore the font will not be changed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\submissiondate}{}
\newcommand{\submitted}[1]{\renewcommand{\submissiondate}{#1}}
\newcommand{\theadvisor}{}
\newcommand{\advisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\theadvisor}{#1}}

\newcommand{\titlepage}{%
\scshape
\vspace{4em}

\begin{center}
\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}
\vspace{3em}

\normalsize
Doctoral dissertation

\small By

\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries\scshape\theauthor\scshape\mdseries
\vspace{30em}

Submitted\\
\submissiondate
\end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}% <-- Changed!
\title{How to not suck at things}
\author{Ink Blot}
\submitted{Decembuary 2017}
\advisor{Professor Professorson}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha. Those bastards tried to sneak a slanted font on me. The rest of the file has a different header/footer, which is why it didn't come up before working on the title page. Thanks. Now it works!